# making query from different related tables using codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, view, model

I'm using codeigniter as i mentioned
this is a part of my view code

```
foreach($projects_query as $row)// $row indicates the projects
{ ?>
<tr><td><h3><button type="submit" class="button red-gradient glossy" name = "project_click"  >
<?php echo $row->txtTaskName; ?></button></h3></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<?php
foreach($tasks_query as $row2)
{ 
//  if( $row->txtTaskName == "TestProject")
if($row->intTaskID == $row2->intInside)// intInside indicades that the current task($row2) is the subset of which task (system , subsystem or project)
{  
              if($row2->intSummary == 0)//if the task(the system) is an executable task & doesn't have any subtask:
              {
                  $query_team_user_id = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_user_team_task_query($row2->intTaskID);//runs the function and generates a query from tbl_userteamtask where intTaskID equals to the selected row's intTaskID
                  foreach($query_team_user_id as $row_teamid)
                  {
                      $query_teamname = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_team_name($row_teamid->intTeamID);
                      $query_fn_ln = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_fn_ln_from_userid($row_teamid->intUserID);
                      foreach($query_teamname as $row_teamname) 
                      {?>
                         <tr><td></td><td></td><td><h4> <?php echo $row2->txtTaskName;?></h4></td>
                         <td><b><font color='#F33558'><?php echo $row_teamname->txtTeamName;?></font></b></td>
               <?php  }
                      foreach($query_fn_ln as $row_f_l_name) 
                      {?>
                         <td> <?php echo $row_f_l_name->txtFirstname." ".$row_f_l_name->txtLastname;?></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <?php }?>
                      </tr>
          <?php  }
              }
              else{ ?> <tr><td></td><td></td><td><h4> <?php echo $row2->txtTaskName;?></h4></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><?php }

         foreach($tasks_query as $row_subsystems)
         {
                   if($row_subsystems->intInside == $row2->intTaskID )//if the task is the subtask of a system(it means the task is a subsystem)
                   {
                       if($row_subsystems->intSummary == 0)//if the task is an executable task & doesn't have any subtask:
                                {
                                   $query_team_user_id = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_user_team_task_query($row_subsystems->intTaskID);
                                   foreach($query_team_user_id as $row_teamid)
                                    {?>
                                       <tr><?php
                                        $query_teamname = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_team_name($row_teamid->intTeamID);
                                        $query_fn_ln = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_fn_ln_from_userid($row_teamid->intUserID);
                                        foreach($query_teamname as $row_teamname) 
                                        {?>
                                           <td></td><td></td><td><h5><?php echo $row_subsystems->txtTaskName?></h5><br/></td>
                                           <td><b><font color='#F33558'><?php echo $row_teamname->txtTeamName;?></font></b></td><?php
                                        }
                                        foreach($query_fn_ln as $row_f_l_name) 
                                        {?>
                                           <td><?php echo $row_f_l_name->txtFirstname." ".$row_f_l_name->txtLastname;?></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><?php
                                        }?>
                                        </tr><?php
                                    }
                                } 
                                else{ ?><tr><td></td><td></td><td><h5><?php echo $row_subsystems->txtTaskName?></h5></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><?php }
                                  foreach($tasks_query as $row_tasks)
                                  {
                                            if($row_tasks->intInside == $row_subsystems->intTaskID )//if the task is the subtask of a subsystem
                                              { 
                                                           if($row_tasks->intSummary == 0)//if the task is an executable task & doesn't have any subtask:
                                                          {
                                                              $query_team_user_id = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_user_team_task_query($row_tasks->intTaskID);
                                                              foreach($query_team_user_id as $row_teamid)
                                                              {?>
                                                                  <tr><?php
                                                                  $query_teamname = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_team_name($row_teamid->intTeamID);
                                                                  $query_fn_ln = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_fn_ln_from_userid($row_teamid->intUserID);
                                                                 foreach($query_teamname as $row_teamname) 
                                                                  {?>
                                                                      <td></td><td></td><td><b><?php echo $row_tasks->txtTaskName;?></b></td>
                                                                      <td><b><font color='#F33558'><?php echo $row_teamname->txtTeamName;?></font></b></td><?php
                                                                  }
                                                                  foreach($query_fn_ln as $row_f_l_name) 
                                                                  {?>
                                                                     <td><?php echo $row_f_l_name->txtFirstname." ".$row_f_l_name->txtLastname;?></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><?php
                                                                  }?>
                                                                  </tr><?php
                                                              }
                                                          } 

                                           }
                                   }
              }

           }

         }



 }

}?>
```

and in controller i have

```
$projects_query = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_projects();                
$tasks_query = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_systems();
$userteamtask = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_user_team_task();

$data['tasks_query'] = $tasks_query;
$data['projects_query'] = $projects_query;

$this->load->view('project_view',$data);
```

but as you see I'm calling my model functions within the view
how can i do  something else to do this i mean not calling my model function in my view

I have to add that, my model function have parameters
these are the model functions:

```
    function get_projects()
    {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
            $this -> db -> from('tbl_task');
    $this -> db -> where('intInside','0');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();             
}

function get_systems()
    {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
    $this -> db -> from('tbl_task ');

    $this -> db -> where('intInside <> ','0');
        $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();     
}


    function get_user_team_task_query($task_id)//gets information from tbl_userteamtask where the field intTaskID is equal to $task_id
    {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
            $this -> db -> from('tbl_userteamtask');
    $this -> db -> where('intTaskID',$task_id);
    $query_teamid = $this->db->get();
    return $query_teamid->result();
}   

    function get_user_team_task()//gets information from tbl_userteamtask where the field intTaskID is equal to $task_id
    {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
            $this -> db -> from('tbl_userteamtask');
 // $this -> db -> where('intTaskID',$task_id);
    $query_teamid = $this->db->get();
    return $query_teamid->result();
}   

function get_team_name($query_teamid)
    {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
    $this -> db -> from('tbl_team');
    $this -> db -> where('intTeamID',$query_teamid);
    $query_teamname = $this->db->get();
    return $query_teamname->result();
}   

function get_user_name($query_userid)
    {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
    $this -> db -> from('tbl_user');
    $this -> db -> where('intUserID',$query_userid);
    $query_username = $this->db->get();
    return $query_username->result();
}

function get_fn_ln_from_userid($selected_id)
{
        $this -> db -> select('tbl_user.intUserID, tbl_user.intPersonID,tbl_person.intPersonID,tbl_person.txtFirstname, tbl_person.txtLastname');
        $this -> db -> from('tbl_user , tbl_person');
        $where = "tbl_user.intPersonID = tbl_person.intPersonID ";
        $this -> db -> where($where);
        $this -> db -> where('tbl_user.intUserID', $selected_id);
        $query = $this -> db -> get();//makes query from DB
        return $query->result();            
    }
```

do I have to use subquery ?

is this true? i mean can i do this?

```
foreach( $data as $key => $each )
{
    $data[$key]['team_id']    = $this->get_user_team_task_query( $each['intTaskID'] ); 
    foreach($data[$key]['team_id'] as $key_teamname => $each)
    {
         $data[$key_teamname]['team_name']    = $this->get_team_name( $each['intTeamID'] ); 
    }

}
```

the model code:

```
foreach( $data as $key => $each )
{
     $data[$key]['intTaskID']  = $each['intTaskID'];
     $data[$key]['team_id']    = $this->get_user_team_task_query( $each['intTaskID'] ); 
     foreach($data[$key]['team_id'] as $key => $each)
     {
        $data[$key]['team_name']    = $this->get_team_name( $each['intTeamID'] ); #fetching of the teamname and saving in the array
        $data[$key]['user_name']    = $this->get_fn_ln_from_userid( $each['intUserID'] );
        foreach($data[$key]['user_name'] as $key => $each)
        {
            $data[$key]['first_name']    =  $each['txtFirstname'] ;
            $data[$key]['last_name']    =  $each['txtLastname'] ;                      
        }
        $data[$key]['first_name'] = $data[$key]['first_name'];
        $data[$key]['last_name'] = $data[$key]['last_name'];
     }
```

}

a part of view code:

```
foreach($tasks_query as $row_systems)
{ 
   if($row->intTaskID == $row_systems['intInside'])// intInside indicades that the current task($row2) is the subset of which task (system , subsystem or project)
    {?>
       <tr><td></td><td></td><td><h4> <?php echo $row_systems['txtTaskName'];?></h4></td><?php
       foreach($tasks_query as $row_subsystems)
        { 
            if($row_systems['intTaskID'] == $row_subsystems['intInside'])
            {?>
                 <tr><td></td><td></td><td><h4> <?php echo $row_subsystems['txtTaskName'];?></h4></td><?php
                 foreach($tasks_query as $row_tasks)
                 { 
                    if($row_subsystems['intTaskID'] == $row_tasks['intInside'])
                    {?>
                          <tr><td></td><td></td><td><h4> <?php echo $row_tasks['txtTaskName'];?></h4></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row_tasks['team_name'];?>   </td>
                          <td><?php echo $row_tasks['first_name'];?>   </td>
                          <?php  
                    }
                 }
           }
      }
```

} ?>

Comment: Paste only the relevant code.

Comment: this is only the relevant code !!

Comment: Not subquery, make a `2d array` of the data you want, and then pass it  on to the controller, In view, just loop the data and print.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to your controller, then pass it to the view.

Comment: the problem is that I pass parameters to my model & that parameters are becoming filled in view

Comment: I mean that these model functions return a value for specific data

Answer (score 0):

Just for example, you are looping around `foreach($projects_query as $row)` and you call `get_projects()` for this. And in the loop you are calling `get_team_name($team_id)` with the`team_id`, right? Now, just change your model function `get_projects()` a little to get the `team name` at once:

```
function get_projects()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_task');
    $this->db->where('intInside','0');
    $query  = $this->db->get();
    //return $query->result();   //instead of returning loop here and fetch the team name  
    $data   = $query->result_array();
    if( is_array( $data ) && count( $data ) > 0 ){
        foreach( $data as $key => $each ){
            $data[$key]['team_name']    = $this->get_team_name( $each['intTeamID'] ); //fetching of the teamname and saving in the array
        }
    }
    return $data; //Now return the data array. :D        
}
```

In view:

```
//$query_team_user_id = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_user_team_task_query($row2->intTaskID); #you dont need it now if you make a 2d array 
foreach($row['team_name'] as $row_teamid){    #changed $query_team_user_id to $row['team_name'] as this will now represent an array
    //inside the loop
}
```

Similarly, you need to fetch all the relevant data that you need to print in your page in the model itself and no need to call from the view.
Hope this helps you.

**Update:**

```
foreach( $data as $key => $each )
{
    $data[$key]['intTaskID']    = $each['intTaskID'];
    $data[$key]['team_id']      = $this->get_user_team_task_query( $each['intTaskID'] ); 
    foreach($data[$key]['team_id'] as $key => $each)
    {
        $data[$key]['team_name']    = $this->get_team_name( $each['intTeamID'] ); #fetching of the teamname and saving in the array
        $user_name    = $this->get_fn_ln_from_userid( $each['intUserID'] ); #you are returning tbl_person.txtFirstname, tbl_person.txtLastname from get_fn_ln_from_userid() with ->result()?
        $data[$key]['first_name']   =  $user_name->txtFirstname; #changes here
        $data[$key]['last_name']    =  $user_name->txtLastname;  #changes here 
    }
}
```

Always remember what you are returning from your functions and change your code as expected results you will be getting. Try to debug your code in the loop for the returned values and change your code accordingly. For example :

```
foreach( $data as $key => $each )
{
    $data[$key]['intTaskID']    = $each['intTaskID'];
    $data[$key]['team_id']      = $this->get_user_team_task_query( $each['intTaskID'] ); 
    foreach($data[$key]['team_id'] as $key => $each)
    {
        echo "<pre>";print_r( $each );die; #will print the $each
        $data[$key]['team_name']    = $this->get_team_name( $each['intTeamID'] ); #fetching of the teamname and saving in the array
        $user_name    = $this->get_fn_ln_from_userid( $each['intUserID'] ); #you are returning tbl_person.txtFirstname, tbl_person.txtLastname from get_fn_ln_from_userid() with ->result()?
        echo "<pre>";print_r( $user_name );die;  #will print the returned results from the get_fn_ln_from_userid()
        $data[$key]['first_name']   =  $user_name->txtFirstname; #changes here
        $data[$key]['last_name']    =  $user_name->txtLastname;  #changes here 
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for the attention. there is something else: the intTeamID is note in tbl_task thats in another table named tbl_userteamtask that relates these 3 tables. a wanted to add my database schema, but i didn't have the permition

Comment: Just make different function(s) for fetching different terms. I just showed you an example. Try it out and if you face further problem just let me know.

Comment: is $data a 2 dimensional array? then how can I use it in view and controller?

Comment: No need to change anything in controller, just in view you need to stop calling the model function(s) and loop correctly, just check out your array structure by printing it in the controller.

Comment: do I have to do this part for all the fields that i want?   $data[$key]['team_name'] = $this->get_team_name( each['intTeamID'] );                                                                  I mean for example :                                         $data[$key]['user_name'] = $this->get_user_name( $each['intUserID'] );  inorder not to lose the other fields

Comment: Yes, follow this `$data[$key]`, this maintains the `key` of the array so you are just appending `extra element` to the array, just make sure that you don't name existing element again or that will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: is this true? i mean can i do this? foreach( $data as $key => $each )
                    {
                        $data[$key]['team_id']    = $this->get_user_team_task_query( $each['intTaskID'] ); 
                        foreach($data[$key]['team_id'] as $key_teamname => $each)
                        {
                            $data[$key_teamname]['team_name']    = $this->get_team_name( $each['intTeamID'] ); #fetching of the teamname and saving in the array
                        }
                        
                    } I've also added this question to the main post

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see for yourself. I showed you an approach now try it out and see if it works or not.

Comment: I've done the changes. in view I face this error: Trying to get property of non-object for the line I'm using the query. & I think that my query know, is in type of array. I can't use it in foreach.

Comment: Yes, may be cause i used `result_array()` and you were using `result()`, I would suggest you to see the structure of the array before using it by `print_r($the_array);die;`.

Comment: yes you were right. i did read the structure and somehow correct it. but something else happened , now in view it doesn't know team_name it gives me the error:  Undefined index: team_name

Comment: post you array structure here. and if it helped you consider accepting the answer too.

Comment: but it still gives me the error : Undefined index: team_name and also for first_name & last_name :(

Comment: see above for updation on the model function.

Comment: for the answer of your question: no i've changed my model functions return values, I mean i've put result_array() instead of result(). now do I have to make the changes you said?

Comment: Just try to follow the debugging i explained. That is your answer to everything. Try it out. I can't spoonfeed you everything frnd. :D

Comment: echo it out in the controller too, and in view separately to find out  where the problem exists.

Comment: it's correct when echoing from the model but it doesn't echo in the view. I think there's something wrong with the passing the data from model to controller. the point is that it echos the txtTaskName correctly but not the other things !!! such a flip I am :D

Comment: even in the controller it doesn't work out. it's ok with txtTaskName I mean in the controller it echos txtTaskName but it doesn't echo team_name or ... !! my code for echoing in the controller is:                                              $tasks_query = $this->admin_in_out_model->get_systems();
 foreach($tasks_query as $row)
 echo $row['team_name'];

Comment: I think i made you upset. but really i tried my best and did all the appropriate changes... but it didn't work :( feeling sad , upset ...

Comment: Okay, it happens. No problem give me your email. We can continue this over mail if you want. :D @fk